# Turning string input into boolean

Tags: c++, string, char, switch-statement, boolean

I am trying to figure out how to turn a user text input of "yes" or "Yes" or "no" into a boolean true/false variable. I was wondering if I could do this using switch functions.

Comment: You can't `switch` on a string, unfortunately. I'd convert the string to all one lower (or all upper) case to reduce the number of comparisons required and then use `if`.

Comment: No, switch statements can't be used with strings.

Comment: Start from something you know how to do, then work your way to your goal. What's your starting point for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to do so.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // For the std::transform() function.

int main()
{
    std::string inCommand;

    std::getline(std::cin, inCommand);
    std::transform(inCommand.begin(), inCommand.end(), inCommand.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    
    bool command = inCommand == "yes";
    return 0;
}
```